# How important is it to have matching sets of RAM?

Tags: memory

How important is it to have matching sets of RAM?  My workstation came with 6GBs of RAM. 3x2GB's

Its now time to install another 6Gbs. Is it absolutely crucial I order the same RAM?

My motherboard is a Asus P6TDeluxe v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. There's a minor speed difference, but adding RAM will always make it faster, even if they don't match.

Source: My laptop and desktop had non-matching set of RAM.

EDIT:
According to http://guides.macrumors.com/Buying_RAM (applicable for PC as well)

> Dual Channel: many Apple machines use
>   dual channel memory. In a few cases,
>   this means that memory must be
>   installed in matched pairs. Your
>   computer's manual would say so if
>   that's true. For the majority of
>   cases, unpaired chips will work fine,
>   but matched pairs will result in a
>   slight speed increase (on the order of
>   a few percent).

Then about the cheapest memory matter:

> When buying memory, it is generally
>   not advisable to go with the absolute
>   cheapest stuff you can find. Low
>   quality memory can and often will
>   cause application crashes, total
>   machine crashes, and data corruption.
>   Do your homework on quality reputation
>   up front, and be advised that while
>   buying generic memory saves you money,
>   you assume a greater risk of trouble
>   later on.

Comment: So mainly the timing should be the same at least? Reason I ask is first set of RAM I got was pretty expensive, I've since found cheaper RAM.

Comment: Yes, if you mean the speed, then it does need to be the same. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: BTW before you upgrade make sure your OS support 12GB of ram...

Comment: Good point - OS (Win764bit Ultimate) should I think. I got other problems now trying to fit in an extra 6GBs into my mobo. My after market cooler is kinda blocking the one ram slot.