# Changing to dual ram

Tags: memory

1st off please understand I am not a computer guy so please show me mercy on improper use of terminology and realize my questions will reveal my lack of knowledge when it comes to computers.

I just bought an Acer Aspire 5 that comes with 4 GB DDR4 ram. It has an open slot so that I may change it to dual ram which I understand gives it better performance. I ordered 1 stick of 16 GB DDR4 to add to the open slot. Then I remembered that it seems that once someone told me when you run dual ram your 2 sticks should match as far as how much ram each contains. Is this true or will I be ok adding the 16 GB stick next to the 4 GB stick?

Also it comes with 128 gb NVMe installed  with an m.2 connection. There is an empty slot for a 2.5" SATA drive and the computer comes with all necessary parts to install a spare drive.

This is where I will look dumb. What is a SATA drive? What do I have to gain by installing one? Does it just go right in and it is recognized? Or do I need to do something after the physical installation of the SATA drive?

Thanks in advance for your patience with my lack of knowledge and thanks for any help you so kindly take the time to give to me. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: It is best to buy a dual ram kit.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  In the future, please ask one Question per Question.

Comment: Dual RAM won't get you much performance, if anything. See [this link](https://superuser.com/a/1387017/8672).

Comment: Having 20 GB versus 4 GB will make a large difference in perceived performance, with the way that Chrome and other apps in 2019 use RAM.  That being said, I should have verified in initial comments that this machine uses a 64-bit CPU.

Answer (score 1):

For the RAM, you will have to find out if the original RAM stick is soldered in, or is removable.  If removable, then the best action is to remove it and put in a matching pair, sold as a kit.  If soldered, then find out the original's speed and timing, and buy a matching stick.  Some sites like Crucial will let you search for the proper RAM by model number.  It sounds like you already bought a 16 GB stick.  It doesn't hurt to install it and give it a try.  Look on Youtube for steps on installing RAM.

For the SATA drive, someone wrote out the steps here for a similar model : https://in.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/53260/~/hard-drive-installation-instructions-for-acer-aspire-a515-51-and-a515-51g .  I don't know if that's an exact match for your model, but the process should be similar.  Power it down, remove the lid, find the bracket where the drive goes, install the drive in bracket with the appropriate screws, plug in power and SATA cable, put the lid back on, and power it up again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and wise answer.

Comment: Is it really true "*the best action is to remove it and put in a matching pair*"?  Even [2006 benchmarks](https://www.geekbench.com/blog/2007/06/matched-ram-performance/) show no difference using unmatched...  Other answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/219655/how-important-is-it-to-have-matching-sets-of-ram?rq=1) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/372363/if-one-ddr2-ram-modules-of-a-pair-goes-bad-should-i-replace-the-pair?rq=1) seem to indicate matching is not important since the 1990's.

Comment: At my current workplace, I've had failure to POST from mixed sticks despite speed and timing match, fixed by matching brand, speed, and timing as close as possible.  They were coming mixed out of a big box of junk.  When a matching pair from a new kit is used, we can be certain that they match.  Benchmarks matter in other circumstances, but here we are merely concerned if it POSTs and the OS can make use of it.

Comment: Gentlemen I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me. Christopher Hostage you are very knowledgable and please accept my sincere apologies for asking 2 questions within 1. I did know better. Its good to know that our world is filled with such knowledgable individuals and that they are so kind as to help the less i formed. God bless you all.

Comment: I meant I did NOT know better

Comment: I formed= informed

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to match your memory sticks.  As long as you buy a compatible memory stick that runs the at the same speed as the one installed you are fine.  Yes, there advantages to matching RAM, but if you arent a power user that is trying to eek out every little bit of performance, its not necessary.  With the 4GB built in and the 16 you are adding, you will most likely have more RAM than you will need.

SATA is the standard connection for modern hard drives.  2.5 inches is the smaller of the two sizes.  The other being 3.5 inches.  While your 128 GB NVME is *really* fast, it also *really* small.  This SATA connection will allow you to add another drive for more space.